# Laravel Image Upload Not Working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am working on a simple CMS, where I have a problem with the image-upload, because it just refreshes the create/edit-page, instead of uploading the image. It works when I comment out the image part.

This is my code:

```
public function create()
{
    $packages = Package::all();

    return view('packages.create')->withPackages($packages);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(

        'title'     =>  'required|max:30',
        'content'   =>  'required|max:255',
        'price'     =>  'required|max:15',
        'icon'      =>  'required|image'

    ));

    $package = new Package;

    $package->title = $request->title;
    $package->content = $request->content;
    $package->price = $request->price;

    if ($request->hasFile('icon')){
        $image = $request->file('icon');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

        $package->image = $filename;
    }

    $package->save();

    return redirect()->route('packages.index');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $package = Package::find($id);
    return view('packages.edit')->withPackage($package);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $this->validate($request, array(

        'title'     =>  'required|max:30',
        'content'   =>  'required|max:255',
        'price'     =>  'required|max:15',
        'icon'      =>  'required|image'

    ));

    $package = Package::find($id);

    $package->title = $request->title;
    $package->content = $request->content;
    $package->price = $request->price;

    if ($request->hasFile('icon')){
    //Add new photo
        $image = $request->file('icon');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

        $oldFilename = $package->image;
    //Update DB
        $package->image = $filename;

     //Delete the old photo
        Storage::delete($oldFilename);
    }

    $package->save();

     //Set flash data with success message
    Session::flash('success', 'Pakkeløsningen blev opdateret!');

    // Redirect with flash data to posts.show
    return redirect()->route('packages.index'); 
}
```

And this is my create.blade.php for the PackageController

```
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'packages.store']) !!}

            {{ Form::label('title', 'Titel:') }}
            {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '255')) }}

            {{ Form::label('content', 'Indhold:') }}
            {{ Form::text('content', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'required' => '',  'maxlength' => '255')) }}

            {{ Form::label('price', 'Pris:') }}
            {{ Form::text('price', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}

            {{ Form::label('icon', 'Vælg ikon') }}
            {{ Form::file('icon') }}

            {{ Form::submit('Lav pakkeløsning!!', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block','style' => 'margin-top:20px;')) }}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Aaaand my routes, in case that is where I'm missing something

```
Route::resource('packages', 'PackageController');
```

I do have the Intervention Image in my provider and aliases, and I do have them namespaced in m controller like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Package;
use Session;
use Image;
use Storage;
```

Thanks in advance! And I hope I am not troubling anyone with stupid beginner questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing   enctype Attribute.

Edit `create.blade.php` form open like the following

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'packages.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```